# Laravel ошибка 400 при запросе на API

Tags: php, laravel, api, composer

Я скачал API проекта с Git, успешно запустил его, но при запросе на страницы API, которые указаны в Routes получаю ошибку 400 (Bad Request).

Код файла api.php в routes

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AsteriskEventsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AudioClipsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\BaseNumberController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\EventsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\ExcelController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\PhoneNumberRVHController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\PhoneNumbersController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\SendersController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\TaskController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\TemplateController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DomainController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use \App\Http\Controllers\Api\TemplateMessageController;


Route::middleware(['api'])->group(function () {

    Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/auth', [AuthController::class, 'auth']);
    });

    Route::prefix('asterisk')->group(function () {
       Route::post('/handleEvent', [AsteriskEventsController::class, 'handleEvent']);
    });

    Route::prefix('phoneNumbers')->group(function () {
       Route::post('batchCreate', [PhoneNumbersController::class, 'batchCreate']);
    });

    Route::prefix('events')->group(function(){
       Route::post('create', [EventsController::class, 'create']);
       Route::get('create', [EventsController::class, 'create']);
    });

    Route::middleware('token.auth')->group(function () {
        Route::prefix('templates')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/list', [TemplateController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('/shortList', [TemplateController::class, 'shortList']);
            Route::get('/{id}/', [TemplateController::class, 'show']);
            Route::post('/create', [TemplateController::class, 'store']);
            Route::put('/{id}/update', [TemplateController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{id}/delete', [TemplateController::class, 'destroy']);
        });

        Route::prefix('templateMessages')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/list', [TemplateMessageController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('/shortList', [TemplateMessageController::class, 'shortList']);
            Route::get('/{id}/', [TemplateMessageController::class, 'show']);
            Route::post('/create', [TemplateMessageController::class, 'store']);
            Route::put('/{id}/update', [TemplateMessageController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{id}/delete', [TemplateMessageController::class, 'destroy']);
        });

        Route::prefix('phoneNumberRVH')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/list', [PhoneNumberRVHController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('/shortList', [PhoneNumberRVHController::class, 'shortList']);
            Route::get('/{id}/', [PhoneNumberRVHController::class, 'show']);
            Route::post('/create', [PhoneNumberRVHController::class, 'store']);
            Route::put('/{id}/update', [PhoneNumberRVHController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{id}/delete', [PhoneNumberRVHController::class, 'destroy']);
        });

        Route::prefix('senders')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/list', [SendersController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('/shortList', [SendersController::class, 'shortList']);
            Route::get('/{id}/', [SendersController::class, 'show']);
            Route::post('/create', [SendersController::class, 'store']);
            Route::put('/{id}/update', [SendersController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{id}/delete', [SendersController::class, 'destroy']);
        });

        Route::prefix('baseNumber')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/list', [BaseNumberController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('/shortList', [BaseNumberController::class, 'shortList']);
            Route::get('/{id}/', [BaseNumberController::class, 'show']);
            Route::post('/create', [BaseNumberController::class, 'store']);
            Route::post('/parseFile', [BaseNumberController::class, 'parseFile']);
            Route::post('/{id}/update', [BaseNumberController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{id}/delete', [BaseNumberController::class, 'destroy']);
        });

        Route::prefix('audioClips')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/list', [AudioClipsController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('/shortList', [AudioClipsController::class, 'shortList']);
            Route::get('/{id}/', [AudioClipsController::class, 'show']);
            Route::post('/create', [AudioClipsController::class, 'store']);
            Route::post('/parseFile', [AudioClipsController::class, 'parseFile']);
            Route::post('/{id}/update', [AudioClipsController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{id}/delete', [AudioClipsController::class, 'destroy']);
        });

        Route::prefix('tasks')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/list', [TaskController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('/{id}/', [TaskController::class, 'show']);
            Route::post('/create', [TaskController::class, 'store']);
            Route::post('/parseFile', [TaskController::class, 'parseFile']);
            Route::put('/{id}/update', [TaskController::class, 'update']);
            Route::delete('/{id}/delete', [TaskController::class, 'destroy']);
        });

        Route::prefix('domains')->group(function () {
            Route::get('list', [DomainController::class, 'index']);
            Route::get('shortList', [DomainController::class, 'shortList']);
        });

        Route::prefix('excel')->group(function () {
            Route::post('headers', [ExcelController::class, 'headers']);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Почитайте описание ошибки, едва ли это имеет хоть какое-то отношение к роутеру, Ваш запрос на сервер не правильно составлен и сервер не может его принять и обработать из-за этого.

Comment: и API и фронт который делает запрос к нему взяты с готового проекта, в них нет ошибок;

Фронт делает запрос на localhost/api/users и получает ошибку

Comment: Ну прекрасно, раз нет ошибок, тогда все должно отлично работать. [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Comment: Я предполагаю что ошибка в URL запроса, потому что сервер запущен на localhost

Comment: Ну так дебажте Ваш запрос

Comment: Запрос на главную работает, а на /api/users ошибка 400

Comment: А где Вы там видите такой эндпойнт `/api/users`?

Comment: Route::middleware(['api'])->group(function () {

    Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/auth', [AuthController::class, 'auth']);
    });

Comment: `users` -- в данном случае это префикс для всех роутов вложенных в группу. В группе у Вас всего один роут, вот этот `Route::post('/auth', [AuthController::class, 'auth']);`. [Route Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-prefixes)